# How can I make the line appear besides the dots?

Tags: ggplot2, plot, graph, line

I tried to plot my data but I can only get the points, if I put "linetype" with geom:line it does not appear. Besides, I have other columns in my data set, called SD, SD.1 and SD.2, which are standard deviation values I calculated previously that appear at the bottom. I would like to remove them from the plot and put them like error bars in the lines.

```
library(tidyr)
long_data <- tidyr::pivot_longer(
  data=OD,
  cols=-Days,
  names_to="Strain",
  values_to="OD")

ggplot(long_data, aes(x=Days, y=OD, color=Strain)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point(shape=16, size=1.5) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("Wildtype"="darkorange2", "Winter"="cadetblue3", "Flagella_less"="olivedrab3"))+
labs(title="Growth curve",x="Days",y="OD750",color="Legend")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5,color="black",size=8),
        axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0.5,color="black",size=8),
        plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=13,face = "bold",margin = margin(t=0, r=10,b=10,l=10)),
        axis.title.y =element_text(size=10, margin=margin(t=0,r=10,b=0,l=0)),
        axis.title.x =element_text(size=10, margin=margin(t=10,r=10,b=0,l=0)),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid",colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Quoting my comment from your last question, please share some sample data, e.g., use `dput(OD[1:10, ])` to share a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your data, including all class and structure information.

Comment: It doesn't let me post another question yet. I cannot show you. I will try later. But I don't know if I get the info you need.

Comment: You don't need to post a new question, you need to edit this question.

Comment: 1) I think you might need to add a group information for geom_line, e.g. geom_line(aes(group = Strain))

Comment: 2) my 2 cents worth  i would advise against adding your error bars, this would cause a lot of visual clutter. instead, if you wanna show the error estimate, you might wanna consider geom_ribbon instead

Comment: 3) check out ggh4x::geom_pointpath

Comment: 4) instead of calling your legend “Legend”, maybe consider calling it “Strain” (you would get this for free just by not specifying the name at all;)